# How to know when GitHub Pages finished generating Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I have a complex Jekyll website. Every change can take a few minutes to generate.

On my local machine I can see the progress that tells me when the re-generation finished.

However on GitHub Pages (Enterprise) how do I know if what I am looking at is the latest version or if it is still generating?

I was thinking maybe Jekyll could print a timestamp somewhere when generating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<p>Page version : {{ site.time | date: '%B %d, %Y - %H:%M:%S %Z'}}</p>` in you footer to print datetime on each page.

Don't forget to set your [timezone variable in configuration](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/).

Comment: I assume that if I put it in the footers, it will trigger a regenerate of all the pages all the time right? Maybe I'll just put it in some "about" page...

Comment: Actual version of jekyll regenerates all the pages. Incremental regeneration will only be present in jekyll 3. I don't know when it will be in use at gh-pages. But yes, you can set this in only one page.

Comment: When I use `bundle exec jekyll serve` it doesn't do incremental? It seems to be that it's much faster when I make a small change than when I make a change to a layout file ...

Comment: what is your Jekyll version ?

Comment: 2.4.0, I'm running the basic setup described in the gh-pages documentation, with bundler...

Comment: I confirm incremental regeneration is landing in Jekyll 3 https://jekyllrb.com/news/